# delete generated .js files (from .ts) in folder using webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am trying to delete all `.js` files with in a folder which are generated from `.ts` files (from tsc)  using [clean-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-webpack-plugin)

but it is not deleting specific files, it is deleting all files.

```
             new CleanWebpackPlugin(['app'],
                {
                    root: path.resolve('.'),
                    verbose: true,
                    dry: false,
                    exclude: ['**/*.ts','**/*.html']
                })
```

How can i solve this problem

1. either do not generate .js from tsc just generate bundle.js from webpack
2. delete only .js files and not .ts/.html/.css from a given folder

I also want to delete the `build` folder, seems like I would have to go back to `gulp` for this

Answer (score 1):

sorry my bad... i just had to change it like below to make it work

```
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(['app/**/*.js', 'build/**/*.*'],
                {
                    root: path.resolve('.'),
                    verbose: true,
                    dry: false
                })
```

so basically use reg-ex in paths itself.